# Read GZIP text file from remote server over SFTP

Tags: python, gzip, fabric

I have many large text files on a remote server that I would like to read without unzipping programmatically

I have functionality working for reading a non-GZIP text file from the remote server as well as reading a GZIP text file locally. I am not sure how to combine the two or if it is possible

Below are the individually working pieces of code:

```
from contextlib import closing
from fabric.network import connect
from fabric import state
import gzip

# This successfully reads a non-GZIP text file from user@host:filePath
with closing(connect("user", "host", "port", None)) as ssh:
    with closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp:
        with closing(sftp.open("filePath")) as f:
            for line in f:
                print line

# This successfully reads a GZIP text file locally
with gzip.open("fileName", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't tested however, you can pass the file handler `f` you get from into `gzip.GzipFile` as follows:

```
with closing(connect("user", "host", "port", None)) as ssh:
    with closing(ssh.open_sftp()) as sftp:
        with closing(sftp.open("filePath")) as f:
            with gzip.GzipFile(mode='rb', fileobj=f) as fin:
                for line in fin:
                    print line
```

Comment: Works, even for large (626M when gzipped) text files. Thank you